# Bluetooth remote remapping for PC

Tags: bluetooth, remote-control, remote-connection

My Bluetooth remote has hardcoded functions, for example when I try to hotkey the volume button to make a video pause, it will pause the video and increase volume. How can i remap every key on the remote?

Comment: It might help if you told us brand and model.

Comment: I actually know how to do it now, by using AutoHotkey. Thanks for the reply tho!

Comment: If you have a solution,  you can help other people by posting it as an answer.